# How to define a type with custom values? (typedef, enum)

Tags: c++, types, enums

In my program in many classes I use `Color` as a type, and it should have only `WHITE` and `BLACK` as its possible values.

So for example I want to write:

```
Color c; 
  c = BLACK;
  if(c == WHITE) std::cout<<"blah";
```

and similar stuff. In all my classes and headers I've said `#include "ColorType.h"`, and I have `Color c` as class attributes, but I don't know what to write  in that `ColorType.h`. I've tried some variations of `typedef enum Color` but it didn't quite work out.

Comment: Is Color as class, struct, typedef, enum...?

Comment: @111111 - I think that is what he is asking *us*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
enum Colors { Black, White };


int main()
{
    Colors c = Black;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @Vidak Then you don't know how to write header files.

Answer (score 3):

[Let_Me_Be's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8493263/845092) is the easy/usual way, but C++11 also gives us `class enums` which prevent mistakes if those are the *only* options for colors.  A regular enum lets you do `Colors c = Colors(Black+2);`, which doesn't make sense

```
enum class Colors  { Black, White };
```

You can (somewhat) duplicate this functionality with C++03 via things like: ([IDEOne demo](http://ideone.com/pGj9t))

```
class Colors {
protected:
    int c;
    Colors(int r) : c(r) {}
    void operator&(); //undefined
public:
    Colors(const Colors& r) : c(r.c) {}
    Colors& operator=(const Colors& r) {c=r.c; return *this;}
    bool operator==(const Colors& r) const {return c==r.c;}
    bool operator!=(const Colors& r) const {return c!=r.c;}
    /*  uncomment if it makes sense for your enum.
    bool operator<(const Colors& r) const {return c<r.c;}
    bool operator<=(const Colors& r) const {return c<=r.c;}
    bool operator>(const Colors& r) const {return c>r.c;}
    bool operator>=(const Colors& r) const {return c>=r.c;}
    */
    operator int() const {return c;} //so you can still switch on it

    static Colors Black;
    static Colors White;
};
Colors Colors::Black(0);
Colors Colors::White(1);

int main() {
    Colors mycolor = Colors::Black;
    mycolor = Colors::White;
}
```